# Set index on formControlName - Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms

I´m using a ngFor on HTML template. I want to put name+ index on formControlName but I can t.

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
  <div formArrayName="controllerArray" >
    <div *ngFor="let item of formName.controls.controllerArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="controlerInputName"**+i**>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have wrapped in  **formArrayName** then you should bind **[formControlName]="i"**

to be lik e

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
  <div formArrayName="controllerArray" >
    <div *ngFor="let item of formName.controls.controllerArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: And without formArrayName how could I do that?

Comment: array name is one of the way other would be [formControl]="formName.controls.controllerArray.controls[i]"

Comment: why can t I do something like this directly ->  <input formControlName="controlerInputName"**+i**>?